# Spring MockMVC MockMultipartFile: Unable to stub method using the mock file getInputStream()

Tags: spring, spring-boot, mockito, spring-test

I am unable to stub the MockMultipartFile InputStream, because every time it calls getInputStream it constructs a new ByteArrayInputStream.

```
@Override
public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
    return new ByteArrayInputStream(this.content);
}
```

Thus when I stub my InputService, I am unable to return the

```
final Integer value1 = 2023;
final Boolean value2 = Boolean.TRUE;
final MockMultipartFile file = new MockMultipartFile(
    "file",
    "file.csv",
    MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE,
    "Hello, World!".getBytes()
);

when(inputService.validateInput(value1, value2, file.getInputStream()))
    .thenReturn(ValidationResult.builder().build());

mockMvc.perform(multipart("/file/validate")
        .file(file)
        .param("value1", value1.toString())
        .param("value2", value2.toString())
    )
    .andDo(print()).andExpect(status().isOk())             
    .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
```

When my controller calls the inputService, it will return `null` and not the object I create within `thenReturn`.

How can I stub `inputService.validateInput` here such that validateInput will return the object I create in the test?

I tried using both anyObject() and any(InputStream.class), but it does not work.

```
final InputStream inputStream = ArgumentMatchers.any(InputStream.class);
```

> Invalid use of argument matchers!

Comment: Use a matcher instead of actual values, something like `eq(value1), eq(value2), any(InputStream.class)`.

Comment: I tried using any(InputStream.class) and anyObject, but those does not work.

Comment: Please show what you tried, as that should work, make sure your other matchers are proper as well!.

Comment: If I use any(InputStream.class) only on the last argument, I get "Invalid use of arguments". Although if I use what you suggest, `eq(value1), eq(value2), any(InputStream.class)`. It fails like before that the return object is null.

Comment: The error clearly states you are using the matchers wrong, you haven't done as I stated in my comment. Your `when` should look like `when(inputService.validateInput(eq(value1), eq(value2), any(InputStream.class)))`, that is a proper use of matchers. If you use matchers everything has to be matchers else it will give you an error.

Comment: `when(inputService.validateInput(eq(value1), eq(value2), any(InputStream.class))).thenReturn(ValidationResult.builder().build());`

Comment: Instead of `any(InputStream.class)` try `any()` instead. Also what is the signature of your `validateInput` method.

Comment: It works with `any()`, but not with `any(InputStream.class)`.

Comment: `public ValidationResult validateInput(final Integer value1, final boolean value2, final InputStream inputStream)`

Comment: `Boolean` isn't a `boolean`, hence it doesn't match.

Comment: My bad. Typo. Should be `boolean` in the test, not `Boolean`.

Answer (score 0):

It worked by using `org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any()` to match the InputStream.

```
when(inputService.validateInput(eq(value1), eq(value2), any()))
    .thenReturn(ValidationResult.builder().build());
```

It did not work using `org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any(InputStream.class)`.

Although since `MockMultipartFile` constructs an `ByteArrayInputStream` when calling `getInputStream()`, it did work by specify `ByteArrayInputStream.class` to `any()`.

```
when(inputService.validateInput(eq(value1), eq(value2), any(ByteArrayInputStream.class)))
    .thenReturn(ValidationResult.builder().build());
```

Comment: `any()` matches `null`, `any(InputStream.class)` only matches non-null input streams.